# Dependencies are not added to archetype

Tags: maven

I'm creating an archetype and I need StringUtils library to use in the groovy script after.

So, I add it to my pom and build it, it works. But when I use the archetype from the command line it complains about a not found StringUtils. Going inside of the jar I can see that, indeed, the StringUtils dependency has not been provided.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my pom

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<build>
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
    <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-archetype.version}</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>

<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Required so that .gitignore gets included in archetypes -->
        <!-- See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-190 -->
        <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-archetype.version}</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```